# Spark submit on Kubernetes cloud engine using only one node, one cpu requested

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have set up a cluster with 4 nodes each having 2 CPUs so 8 in total.
My code end up running only on one CPU and no matter the settings the requested CPUs is always 1 in the pod description and the execution time stays the same. Tried the spark examples and same thing applies.

Spark submit script I use:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://https://34.64.87.144 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name spark-counter \
--class DataCounter \
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:////opt/spark/data/log4j.properties" \
--conf spark.executor.cores=4 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.request.cores=3.6 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-counter \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=asia.gcr.io/profound-media-298808/spark-base:latest \
local:///opt/spark/data/spark_counter-1.0.jar /opt/spark/data/input1
```

and the description of the pod

```
spark-role=driver
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Succeeded
IP:           10.32.4.37
IPs:
  IP:  10.32.4.37
Containers:
  spark-kubernetes-driver:
    Container ID:  containerd://bd31b8112159145169ab1b6397af8bc2f10cee5429b11c8025f2359ab5194882
    Image:         asia.gcr.io/profound-media-298808/spark-base:latest
    Image ID:      asia.gcr.io/profound-media-298808/spark-base@sha256:6aaf817da5606a39bf2aeea769c4ec2d62c7986d06109cb4a38f4f7157702ff1
    Ports:         7078/TCP, 7079/TCP, 4040/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      driver
      --properties-file
      /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties
      --class
      DataCounter
      spark-internal
      /opt/spark/data/input1
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Fri, 18 Dec 2020 07:13:45 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 18 Dec 2020 07:14:28 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  1408Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  1408Mi
    Environment:
      SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS:   (v1:status.podIP)
      SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS:           /var/data/spark-f4832458-7450-4d96-b7ed-c672d5ec0eda
      SPARK_CONF_DIR:             /opt/spark/conf
    Mounts:
      /opt/spark/conf from spark-conf-volume (rw)
      /var/data/spark-f4832458-7450-4d96-b7ed-c672d5ec0eda from spark-local-dir-1 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from spark-token-5zk2c (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  spark-local-dir-1:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  spark-conf-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      spark-counter-1608275621712-driver-conf-map
    Optional:  false
  spark-token-5zk2c:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  spark-token-5zk2c
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    7m44s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/spark-counter to gke-cluster-1-default-pool-f51b7df5-g048
  Warning  FailedMount  7m43s (x2 over 7m43s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "spark-conf-volume" : configmap "spark-counter-1608275621712-driver-conf-map" not found
  Normal   Pulled       7m42s                  kubelet            Container image "asia.gcr.io/profound-media-298808/spark-base:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created      7m42s                  kubelet            Created container spark-kubernetes-driver
  Normal   Started      7m42s                  kubelet            Started container spark-kubernetes-driver
```

I have no additional configuration files set up, using the spark image builder script as a base to build the image used only adding my own jar and data to it. Should I have something more?

How do I set up my cluster to utilize all nodes?

Comment: Have you tried to run your workload on a node that has more than 2 cores? It may be requesting only 1 as there are already other resources taking the cpu.

Comment: You're showing the driver with just 1 CPU core (the default). You've requested `spark.executor.cores=4`. Can you check out the executors' CPU cores then?